# How to scale VoltDB on 3 machines

Tags: voltdb

I am new to VoltDB and working on a college research project. For that I need to run VoltDB on multiple nodes. Currently, I have 3 Ubuntu 16.04 VMs on Azure cloud. Each with 8 vCPUs, 200GB storage,  32 GB ram. All of them has VoltDB 8.1.1 community edition running on them indepently.

I need to know the steps how to combine them as 1 cluster. I tried modifying deployment.xml kfactor 3 but not able make 1 cluster.

Please guide me with steps on how to achieve horizontal scaling of VoltDB using community edition.

In future, I am trying add at least 12 more nodes to the cluster.

Any help is appreciated!!!

Comment: Yes, my issue is resolved. I am unable to update answer on my profile due to insufficient rank

Answer (score 0):

What does your deployment.xml file look like? An example of a deployment file that can work for a 3 node cluster is below:

```
<deployment>
   <cluster hostcount="3" kfactor="1"/>
   <httpd enabled="true">
      <jsonapi enabled="true" />
   </httpd>
</deployment>
```

After initializing with voltdb init:

```
voltdb init --force --config=deployment.xml
```

You can start the cluster:

```
voltdb start --host=server1,server2,server3
```

Note that server1, server2, and server3 should be replaced with either a unique host name or IP address. What these are will depend on your Azure setup.

Kfactor is not the same as the number of nodes. It is the maximum number of nodes that can die before the cluster shuts down entirely. More information on it can be found here:

https://docs.voltdb.com/UsingVoltDB/KSafeEnable.php

Disclosure: I work at VoltDB

Comment: While running voltdb init --force --config=deployment.xml                            ERROR: Deployment information could not be obtained from cluster node or locally
VoltDB has encountered an unrecoverable error and is exiting.

Comment: I am able to init voltDB on 3 nodes using the deployment.xml but now when I start the  VoltDB on first node by issuing command `code` ~/voltdb-community-8.1.2/bin$ ./voltdb start --host=“X.X.X.5,X.X.X.6,X.X.X.7” the terminal is not showing anything. I also tried starting voltDB on node 2 and node 3 by issuing voltbd start but voltdb is not starting. in logs I see error  2018-06-15 03:27:11,287   INFO  [Leader elector-/db/leaders/globalservice] HOST: Host 0 promoted to be the global service provider
2018-06-15 03:27:11,298   FATAL [main] HOST: Not enough nodes to ensure K-Safety.

Comment: Thanks for all your help Andrew. I figured the issue was with quotes " I reissued the command by removing it. :) ~/voltdb-community-8.1.2/bin$ ./voltdb start --host=X.X.X.5,X.X.X.6,X.X.X.7

Comment: Great. Glad I could help. Please mark this answer correct if your issue is solved.